# How to Close and Open, one after the other on a div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Basically, I'm trying to easily refresh a collapsible div. Wherein when I want to change the data, I can run a script, that basically closes and opens the div if it is open, and simply opens the div if it is closed.
My aim is to use something similar to this.

```
$("#procDiv").html("New Data");
if($("#procDiv").attr('class').contains("collapse in")) {
    $("#procDiv").collapse("close");
    $("#procDiv").collapse("open");
} else {
    $("#procDiv").collapse("open");
}
```

But I am having an issue as it doesn't open when I tell it to open which would be from what I would assume to be from the fact that it is in an animation and so it doesn't expect any new instructions.

HTML

```
<form class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="sr-only" for="inputAirport">Airport</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputAirport" placeholder="Airport">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-search">Search</button>
</form>

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#procDiv">Procedures</a>
        </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="procDiv" class="panel-collapse collapse"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: where did u write this script? on document ready?

Comment: @Se0ng11 it runs when the user clicks a button

Comment: add html code here...

Comment: @BhavinSolanki added relevant HTML

Answer (score 1):

```
if($("#procDiv").hasClass("collapse in")) {
    $("#procDiv").slideDown();
} else {
    $("#procDiv").slideUp();
}
```

Try in this way.

By the way, there is syntax error on line 2 in your code. You missed double quote

Comment: I'm looking for something that doesn't simply opens or closes a div, but rather opens AND closes a div, one after the other. So as if it looks like it is refreshing the visible data.

Comment: Then you can do using default functionality of `carousel jquery` or using `nth-child`